# First exit time of a simple random walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $S_n=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ be the simple random walk with $S_0=0$. Now define the stopping time  $$\tau=\inf\{n>0| S_n\notin (a,b)\}.$$

I am trying to follow some steps in a book and just need to understand how it ends up with the following inequalities with the goal of showing that $E(\tau)<\infty$.

$$P(S_{b-a}\notin (a,b))\geq2^{-(b-a)}$$ and supposedly iterating this gives $$P(\tau>n(b-a))\leq (1-2^{-(b-a)})^n.$$

Can someone explain how we can derive these inequalities? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, $a<0<b$ are integers and the first inequality should be
$$
\mathsf{P}(x+S_{b-a}\notin (a,b))\ge 2^{-(b-a)}, \quad x\in (a,b).
$$
This inequality holds because $\{X_i=1 \text{ for all } 1\le i\le (b-a)\}\subset \{x+S_{b-a}\notin (a,b)\}$ for any $x\in(a,b)$. As for the second inequality,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(\tau> 1(b-a))&\le \mathsf{P}(S_{b-a}\in(a,b))\le 1-2^{-(b-a)}, \\[1em]
\mathsf{P}(\tau>2(b-a))&=\mathsf{P}(\tau>2(b-a),S_{b-a}\in (a,b)) \\
&=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{P}(\tau>2(b-a)\mid S_{b-a})1\{S_{b-a}\in (a,b )\}] \\
&\le \mathsf{E}[\mathsf{P}(S_{b-a}+(S_{2(b-a)}-S_{b-a})\in (a,b)\mid S_{b-a})1\{S_{b-a}\in(a,b)\}] \\
&\le (1-2^{-(b-a)})\mathsf{P}(S_{b-a}\in (a,b))\le (1-2^{-(b-a)})^2, \\[1em]
&\ldots
\end{align}

Comment: hello, how do you come up with the (considering the last paragraph, where you replace $1$ by $2$), the second equality and third inequality.
For now I know : $$ E( X 1_{Y=k} ) = E ( X | Y = k ) P(Y = k) $$
do you use something similar to this?

Comment: @MarineGalantin It's the tower property of conditional expectations (or the [law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)).

Comment: Please, can you elaborate a little bit? I m struggling so much for already a few days.

Comment: So the two lines you wrote (one equality and one inequality) does not make any sense for me. I really don't get how you obtained them. If you give me a formula, please state what stands for what. I m feeling exactly as reeding "I am using the dominated convergence theorem", which can be used in multiple ways. So please, if you can, can you detail as much as you can in order for me to understand the transition ? When I am saying I don't understand, I really have no clue at all.

Comment: (1) For random variables $X$ and $Y$, $\mathsf{E}[Yf(X)]=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[Yf(X)\mid X]]=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[Y\mid X]f(X)]$, where $f$ is any measurable function satisfying $\mathsf{E}|Yf(X)|<\infty$. Now set $Y=1\{\tau>2(b-a)\}$, $X=S_{b-a}$, and $f(x)=1\{x\in(a,b)\}$.

Comment: (2) The third inequality uses the Markov property, i.e. for $x\in (a,b)$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(S_{b-a}+(S_{2(b-a)}-S_{b-a})\in (a,b)\mid S_{b-a}=x)=\mathsf{P}(x+S_{b-a}\in(a,b))
$$
because conditionally on $S_{b-a}$, $(S_{(b-a)+n}-S_{b-a})$, $n\ge 0$,  is a random walk started at $0$. Consequently, we use the first inequality to bound the RHS, i.e. $\mathsf{P}(x+S_{b-a}\in(a,b))\le 1-2^{-(b-a)}$.

Comment: ok for (1) it's alright, for (2), is it this : ?
$$ E[P(S_{b-a} + S_{2(b-a)} - S_{b-a}) \in (a,b) | S_{b-a} ) 1_{ S_{b-a} \in (a,b) } ] $$
$$=E[ P(x+ S_{b-a} \in (a,b) ) \cdot 1_{ S_{b-a} \in (a,b)}  ]$$ 
$$ = P(x+ S_{b-a} \in (a,b) ) \cdot E[1_{ S_{b-a} \in (a,b)}  ] =  P(x+ S_{b-a} \in (a,b))^2$$

Comment: No. $x$ in the second line doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry you're right. I should have put in the first line that the condition is $$ S_{b-a} = x $$ Would it be better ? But nevertheless, I don't understand why you were talking about $ x \in (a,b) $ whereas in your initial answer there is no $x$. How does it appear ? I'm so sorry that I don't understand, I'm trying my best.

Comment: @MarineGalantin Let $\phi(x):=\mathsf{P}(x+S_{b-a}\in (a,b))$. Then
\begin{align}
&\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{P}(S_{b-a}+(S_{2(b-a)}-S_{b-a})\in (a,b)\mid S_{b-a})1\{S_{b-a}\in(a,b)\}] \\
&\qquad=\mathsf{E}[\phi(S_{b-a})1\{S_{b-a}\in(a,b)\}]\le \mathsf{E}[(1-2^{(b-a)})1\{S_{b-a}\in(a,b)\}]  \\
&\qquad=(1-2^{(b-a)})\phi(0)\le (1-2^{(b-a)})^2.
\end{align}

Comment: thank you d.k.o. for your patience. Take care :)

Comment: Hi. I am supposed to solve this problem:let $(S_{1},S_{2},S_{3},...)$ be a symmetric simple random walk (with the step $X_{n}$ taking on only the values $1$ and $-1$ with equal probabilities). Let $\alpha=\min (n:S_{n}=5)$  and $\beta=\min (n:S_{n}<-3)$ and the question is if $$min(\alpha,\beta)+1$$  $$max(\alpha,\beta)-1$$ are stopping times of the sequence $X=(X_{1},X_{2},...)$. I am trying to solve it but with no success.I would appreciate if you could help me. Thanks  in advice.